# PHP Print Date Variable Format

Tags: php

So this should be a real easy question but I can't seem to find a simple answer anywhere.

I'm patching up some PHP code (I'm not a PHP'er) and I have this variable $orderDate. How do I print this variable so that its just M/d/yy h:mm tt?

Update:
So I looked around and saw what $orderDate is. Here's the code:

```
global $orderDate;
$orderDate = strftime('%c');
print("Order Date: ".date("M/d/Y h:M", $orderdate)."<br />");
```

so I get this for output:

> Dec/31/1969 06:Dec

and should be getting today's date....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo date("m/d/Y h:m", $orderDate);
echo date("m/d/Y h:m", strtotime($orderDate)); // or this
```

Depends on what $orderDate contains.

Look into [date()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) since it has there plenty of examples and is pretty simple to use.

UPDATE:

```
$orderDate = date("M/d/Y h:M");
print("Order Date: ".orderDate ."<br />");
```

Also check out to see if this works for you.

Comment: You're welcome, I am also going to update the answer for you.

Comment: God, I wish the PHP manual was this clear. Thanks for the 2 examples.

Answer (score 0):

[`date` function](http://php.net/date) will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

See the PHP [`date()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

> Returns a string formatted according to the given `format` string using the given integer `timestamp` or the current time if no timestamp is given.
>
> ```
> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If $orderDate is an integer time stamp, you probably want [strftime](https://www.php.net/strftime).  Specifically, I think the call you want would be:

```
strftime("%D %l:%M %p", $orderDate)
```

However, I recommend reviewing the web page to make sure I've interpreted what you want correctly.